# Exclude custom options price from sorting

Tags: price, custom-options, sorting

I'm working on a Magento store where there are lots of products with custom options.
I noticed that when I sort category products by price, the displayed value (e.g. 300,00 EUR) is different from the one Magento uses to sort.

I'll try to explain...

1. Product 1: price 100 EUR
2. Product 2: price 90 EUR + 1 required custom option 20 EUR
3. Product 3: price 130 EUR

I would like to see this sort ordeR:

1. Product 2: 90 EUR
2. Product 1: 100 EUR
3. Product 3: 130 EUR

But I see:

1. Product 2: 100 EUR
2. Product 1: 90 EUR
3. Product 3: 130 EUR

Is this the default Magento behavior? can I configure that from the backend area?

Thanks!

Comment: please visit:-http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/add-custom-sort-by-drop-down-menu-options-in-magento/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Magento sorts by the minimum price, which is stored in the price index table and takes required options into account.

In the default theme you should actually see **"as low as 110 EUR"** in the product list. To sort by product price alone, not minimum price, you would have to implement your own sort function.

**Solution:**

A solution without custom code would be to create a new attribute `sort_price`, make it sortable and enter the price that should be used for sorting for every product.

Comment: yes, @fschmengler,i am  agree with you.

Comment: You have remove my   edit: :)

Comment: I improved it :P

Comment: Thanks @fschmengler ! I decided to override the Product Resource Collection class to sort by "final_price" instead of "min_price".